# Look up value in Django json object

Tags: django, json

In a Django view I have an object

```
state_lookup = {"Alabama":"AL", "Alaska":"AK", ... "Wyoming":"WY"}
```

How do I pass a state name to that object and get its abbreviation in return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python dictionaries can be accessed in the same way as lists. Here is an example.

```
state_lookup = {"Alabama":"AL", "Alaska":"AK", ... "Wyoming":"WY"}
state = 'Alabama'
abbrev = state_lookup[state] # abbrev should be 'AL' now
```

Comment: I get this error in django view when trying to access json value of key: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 2):

Mao answer is exact.
Just one note if there is no such key than you'll get an exception.
So sometimes you may want to use:

```
state = 'Alabama'
state_wrong = 'Alibama'

#to get key value with default defined
abbrev = state_lookup.get(state_wrong,None)
assert abbrev == None

#in case of more if... flow
if state_lookup.has_key(state_wrong):
    abbrev = state_lookup[state_wrong]
else:
    abbrev = None
assert abbrev == None
```

To quickly get to speed in python I strongly recommend going through examples from:
http://www.siafoo.net/article/52

Good luck on your python journey!